# Concatenate multiple similar CSV files into one big dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have one directory where there are only the CSV files I want to use. I want to concatenate all these CSV files and create a bigger one. I've tried one code but it didn't work.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

targetdir = r'C:/Users/toshiba/Documents/ICF2011/Base Admision San Marcos 2014-2/Sabado'

filelist = os.listdir(targetdir) 

big_df=pd.DataFrame()
for file in filelist :
    big_df.append(pd.read_csv(file), ignore_index=True)
```

I run the code and a there's a message that says: `IOError: File A011.csv does not exist`.
This is contradictory because `A011.csv` is the first CSV file in the directory that I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listdir` only returns the filename, not the complete path. To get the complete path you will need to join `targetdir` and `file` (bad variable name as it masks the `file` type). Also, you will have to capture the result of `.append` as it returns a new object rather than appending in place.

```
for filename in filelist:
    big_df = big_df.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(targetdir, filename), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, you need to use the full-path, rather than the local path.

I recommend using [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html) rather than [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), as this way you don't make many intermediary frames:

```
big_df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(targetdir, filename),
                               ignore_index=True)
                   for filename in filelist)
```